# PyImport_ImportModule never returns

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm actually a c++ programmer and had to use pybind11 to get some python code run in my application. Everything was fine, but suddenly I no longer can import some of my python libraries using: 'PyImport_ImportModule(const char *name)'.
Whereas importing 'sys' and others works fine, for example importing 'numpy' results in the function never return.
Using the python command line with 'numpy' works fine, though.
The only thing that changed in the last month was that I upgraded to Win10.
Reinstalling 'numpy' did not help.

So, how could I solve this?

edit: the relevant code line is:

```
PyObject *obj = PyImport_ImportModule("numpy");
```

Comment: How are you importing numpy? is the line `import numpy as np` never finishing?

Comment: Sembei, its: PyObject *obj = PyImport_ImportModule("numpy");

Comment: please edit your question to add the relevant code. Don't post it as a comment

Comment: If you're using `pybind11`, you should use `pybind11` methods, like `pybind11::module_::import("numpy")` instead of using raw Python C functions.

Comment: Holt, I do so actually. I just stripped it down so its clear that the problem is within 'PyImport_ImportModule()'